# Arch Linux - Cannot mount SMB Share with mount.cifs, but gvfs and smbclient work

Tags: mount, network-shares, arch-linux, samba, cifs

I am trying to access a NAS over a Cisco AnyConnect VPN.

I can access it fine on:

- Macbook (Finder's "Connect to server")
- Windows 10 (Map Network Drive)
- Arch Linux gvfs (thunar and `gio mount`)
- Arch Linux `smbclient`

I used to be able to mount the same share just fine, but suddenly one, day it stopped working.

When I do `mount -v -t cifs //<server_address>/<share> /mnt/share -o rw,user=<user>,uid=<uid>,gid=<gid>,domain=<domain>`

I get the following error:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=<ip_addr>,unc=\\<server>\<share>,uid=<uid>,gid=<gid>,user=<user>,domain=<domain>,pass=********
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

When looking at dmesg the error I get is

```
Status returned 0x000005e STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS
```

Based on reading I've tried:

- Adding `vers=1.0`, `vers=2.0`, `vers=3.0`
- Trying every iteration of `sec` including `ntlm`, `ntlmssp`, `krb5`, etc

This happens even after full system upgrade (`pacman -Syu`) and reboot. Multiple times.

I've even gone as far as spinning up an Ubuntu 18 VM to try the same command.
The message is an Input/Output error but the `dmesg` is still the same with `STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS`

**SOS! I am losing my sanity**

Here are outputs from my Arch Linux

```
[bnguyen@PHI-JAS ~]$ uname -a
Linux PHI-JAS.bnguyen.org 5.5.13-arch2-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon, 30 Mar 2020 20:42:41 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[bnguyen@PHI-JAS ~]$ mount.cifs --version
mount.cifs version: 6.10
[bnguyen@PHI-JAS ~]$ smbclient --version
Version 4.11.3
[bnguyen@PHI-JAS ~]$ gio --version
2.64.1
[bnguyen@PHI-JAS ~]$ pacman -Q linux
linux 5.5.13.arch2-1
[bnguyen@PHI-JAS ~]$
```

Here is output from my Mac OS X

```
$ smbutil statshares -a

==================================================================================================
SHARE                         ATTRIBUTE TYPE                VALUE
==================================================================================================
<share>                      
                              SERVER_NAME                   <server>
                              USER_ID                       501
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB1_ENABLED
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB2_ENABLED
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB3_ENABLED
                              SMB_VERSION                   SMB_3.0
                              SMB_SHARE_TYPE                DISK
                              SIGNING_SUPPORTED             TRUE
                              EXTENDED_SECURITY_SUPPORTED   TRUE
                              LARGE_FILE_SUPPORTED          TRUE
                              FILE_IDS_SUPPORTED            TRUE
                              QUERYINFO_NOT_SUPPORTED       TRUE
                              DFS_SUPPORTED                 TRUE
                              FILE_LEASING_SUPPORTED        TRUE
                              PERSISTENT_HANDLES_SUPPORTED  TRUE
                              ENCRYPTION_SUPPORTED          TRUE
                              DFS_SHARE                     TRUE

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edit: Worth mentioning there was a time when the command did indeed work.

Comment: Does `/mnt/share` exist?

Comment: also, you probably want to mount as root, or mount to a location in your home.

Comment: `/mnt/share` exists. Tried using `sudo mount`, `sudo su`, as well as using a location in home. No luck.